# about ATL 140 , is it a typo in DECLARE_REGISTRY?

Tags: atl

I'm writing a com component using ATL 140, and use this macro in my component body

```
#define DECLARE_REGISTRY(class, pid, vpid, nid, flags)\
    static HRESULT WINAPI UpdateRegistry(_In_ BOOL bRegister) throw()\
    {\
        return _Module.UpdateRegistryClass(GetObjectCLSID(), pid, vpid, nid,\
            flags, bRegister);\
    }
```

`UpdateRegistry` has a reference to `_Module` and it must be a `CComModule`, since only this class has the `UpdateRegistryClass` method. But per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccommodule-class?view=vs-2019) doc, `CComModule` is deprecated. So should I declare `_Module` as my module and copy `UpdateRegistryClass` and paste to my module? Many thanks!

```
struct MyModule : CAtlExeModuleT<MyModule>
{
  HRESULT WINAPI UpdateRegistryClass(...){...};
};
...
MyModule _Module;
```

Comment: Since this is just an (old) macro, you can either change you module instance name to `_Module` or don't use that macro. I personally re-declare `static HRESULT WINAPI UpdateRegistry(_In_ BOOL bRegister)` w/o any macro

Comment: Ok. That's a workaround.